# What is the time complexity for directed_hausdorff?

Tags: python, scipy, time-complexity

What is the time complexity for `directed_hausdorff` function from scipy?

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import directed_hausdorff

score = directed_hausdorff(img1, img2)[0]
print(score)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.directed_hausdorff.html#scipy.spatial.distance.directed_hausdorff):

> Uses the early break technique and the random sampling approach
> described by [1]. Although worst-case performance is O(m * o) (as with
> the brute force algorithm), this is unlikely in practice as the input
> data would have to require the algorithm to explore every single point
> interaction, and after the algorithm shuffles the input points at
> that. The best case performance is O(m), which is satisfied by
> selecting an inner loop distance that is less than cmax and leads to
> an early break as often as possible. The authors have formally shown
> that the average runtime is closer to O(m).